# How to match the string within nearest brackets in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression to match the following regulation.

Example: '(A or B or C or (D (5w) E)) and (F (5w) (G or H or I))'

Result: '(D (5w) E)', '(F (5w) (G or H or I))'

I have written below regex but it's giving me '(A or B or C or (D (5w) E)', '(F (5w) (G or H or I)' which is not correct.

```
import re

test = '(A or B or C or (D (5w) E)) and (F (5w) (G or H or I))'

print re.findall('\((?:.*?)\(5w\)(?:.*?)\)', test)
```

Can someone help on this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to match any non-greedy set using `.*?`, you should instead match non-greedy set that doesn't contain `(` or `)`. So just replace the first `.*?` pattern by `[^(]*?` and the second one by `[^)]*?`

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> test=  '(A or B or C or (D (5w) E)) and (F (5w) (G or H or I))'
>>> re.findall('\((?:[^(]*?)\(5w\)(?:[^)]*?)\)', test)

['(D (5w) E)', '(F (5w) (G or H or I)']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think there is ')' missing for the second result. It should be '(F (5w) (G or H or I))'. How can I match this kind of much more complicated string '((A or B or C) (5w) (D or E or F))'?